# Multi Values Creatable Autocomplete MUI component

Tags: web, material-ui

There is an awesome example for a creatable autocomplete component on the mui docs [here](https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#creatable)
I am trying to make a **multiple values** creatable autocomplete component but got stuck when i tried the example above as it is for a **single value** autocomplete component
Any idea how to implement it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit the question and share your code!

Comment: @IngoSteinke yea you are right i should have share my code or what I have reached so far. Anyway I implemented it successfully. Thanks for the advice